# AngularJS ng-repeat nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My code is outputting this:

- {"name":"John"}
- {"name":"Mark"}

How can it output this (without editing the `$scope.names` object):

- John
- Mark

Here's my view:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">
                {{name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
  </body>
```

...and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = {
        "1": {
            "name": "John"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Mark"
        }
    };
});
```

Here's my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hnjoPH0r9xhlvMzO93Ts?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{{name.name}}` - you're currently just displaying the entire object being iterated over - you need to specify the property as well.

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">
    {{name.name}}
</li>
```